# How to resize image to fit in its container with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make divs with a constant width and height, that contain an child image with an unknown size.

Something like this:

[image]

The closest i've got is with `max-height: inherit; max-width: inherit` but it changes aspect ratio

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid ;
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1123982/pexels-photo-1123982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" />
</div>
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Without a [reprex], you might want to try `img { width: 100% }` instead of the both `max-` values. With this (and `height: auto`, which is the CSS default value) the image will stretch to fill the available width space and stretch the height to ratio. But without your code it is a bit of a guessing game...

Comment: you should use `object-fit: contain` for your `<img>`

Comment: You can try with the `orientation` media query to set different values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `object-fit:cover` css property to `img` or `video` should be resized to fit its container.

Run Snippet below.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1123982/pexels-photo-1123982.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" />
</div>
```

Comment: Would this work if `.parent` got its size from `flex:1` instead of `width` and `height`?