# How do to center the image even though the width of the div is smaller then the image width

Tags: html, css, centering

Currently, my image is center within it's div, but when i make the browser smaller, the image won't move further left to keep center within it's div.

[image]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta property="og:title" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" content="">
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">

  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://development.beeldenfabriek.nl/woningzoeker/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?version=3">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="animation" id="Scene Section">
    <div class="col-7 col-s-12">
      <div class="deel1">
        <div class="imgbox">
          <img src="images/building_rotation/building_rotation_0014.png" class="img">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-s-12">
      <div class="deel2">
        <div class="infobox">
          
        </div>
        <div class="planbox">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* COLUMN STRUCTURE */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}



.deel1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.deel1 .imgbox {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1.0);
}
.deel1 .imgbox .img {
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}




.deel2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
}
.deel2 .infobox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1.0);
}
.deel2 .planbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
}
```

I've tried to take the display: flex; approach and justify-content: center; but it still doesn't keep the image centered when the div gets smaller then the image width.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736264/how-to-resize-image-to-fit-in-its-container-with-css

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, including an actual image we can see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Set the image width to 100%, it will take up the whole width of parent div. Then give the image `object-fit:contain` or `object-fit:cover` (if you want it cropped). The image doesn't need to has a height specified. `height:auto` would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

change the below code in the CSS

```
.deel1 .imgbox {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1.0);

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* if needed */
}
.deel1 .imgbox .img {
  /* justify-content: center; */
  height: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```